# VS 2015 won't compile - "Dependency could not be resolved"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio, dnx

I built an ASP.NET MVC app using Visual Studio RC and have now uninstalled that tool and installed Visual Studio 2015 RTM. Each time I try to build the app `web.app` via `Ctrl-F5`, it throws this error:

> Dependency EntityFramework >= 7.0.0-beta4 could not be resolved    web.app

When I double-click the error, it opens my project.json file.

```
{
    /* Click to learn more about project.json  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=517074 */
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "userSecretsId": "***************************************",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Net.Http.Server": "1.0.0-beta4"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
        "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Net": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Web": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Web.Extensions": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        }
    },

    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],

    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],

    "scripts": {
        "postrestore": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
        "prepare": [ "grunt bower:install" ]
    }
}
```

I updated my PowerShell to 4.0, then updated my DNX using this command:

> PM> Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServer -Pre

which installed `EntityFramework.SqlServer 7.0.0-beta5`. No difference in the error. I'm losing my mind and need to actually get some work done with Visual Studio. Anyone got any answers?

I even tried uninstalling RTM and installing RC, but it said that my app was now incompatible with that edition of Visual Studio. So it seems I can't go back to RC.

Comment: Are you using client profile .net framework?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what is the client profile .net framework? I'm trying to use what came with Visual Studio.

Comment: Check your target Framework in the properties. Sometimes it defaulted to .NET Framework XX Client Profile

Comment: OK. The solution has 2 projects. The non-web app project had target framework set to 4.5, yet, from the project.json above, it seems the framework is 4.51. So I changed it to that. Now I can't get the IISExpress to work -- it's vanished from Visual Studio! Debugging is also grayed out. Arghhh!

Comment: Maybe trying download the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt204009.aspx OR for your first error, trying to install again the "Web Tools extension": https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935?SRC=VSIDE with this command as admin:
"dotnetcore.1.0.0-vs2015tools.preview2 SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1", for more info:
http://www.ryadel.com/en/microsoft-net-core-1-0-0-vs2015-tooling-preview-update-2-fails-install-error-0x81f4000-fix/